# How to programmatically determine tab index of fields on a form based on their X,Y coordinates?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I need to figure out the proper tabbing order of HTML form fields based on their absolute X, Y coordinates on the page. We use X, Y from the bottom-left corner of the `div` (page container) in which they are placed.

For example, in the image below, the numbers inside the boxes indicate the final `tabIndex` order I would expect as the result should the boxes overlap at all on the Y axis; the lowest X axis value would win and the Y axis wouldn't matter at all.  If there's no overlap, then the highest Y axis value wins.

[image]

**Context**

Basically when filling out a PDF form, the natural tab index should be left to right even if box #3 is a little higher than box #2; you'd still want to fill it out left to right. However, since box #1 is on a completely different X plane than the other boxes (regardless if it's further right than the rest) it should still logically come before the other boxes when filling out a form. You wouldn't go across and then up.

The fields are in a C# object with X and Y properties. (pseudocode below)

```
var fields = new List<TestFieldModel>()
{
    new TestFieldModel()
    {
        ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 3,
        PageNumber = 1,
        X = 7,
        Y = 6,
        Width = 5,
        Height = 2
    },
    new TestFieldModel()
    {
        ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 4,
        PageNumber = 1,
        X = 14,
        Y = 4,
        Width = 5,
        Height = 3
    },
    new TestFieldModel()
    {
        ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 1,
        PageNumber = 1,
        X = 17,
        Y = 9,
        Width = 5,
        Height = 3
    },
    new TestFieldModel()
    {
        ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 2,
        PageNumber = 1,
        X = 2,
        Y = 5,
        Width = 4,
        Height = 2
    }
};
```

Comment: Based on what rule, you decided this order? Why "1" is first, and why is "2" the second, and "3" the third?

Comment: Should "2" should be third and "3" should be second based on highest Y value rule?

Comment: @TcKs if the boxes overlap at all in the Y axis, the lowest X axis value wins and the Y axis doesn't matter at all. If there's no overlap, then the highest Y axis value wins.  Basically when filling out a PDF form, the natural tab index should be left to right even if box #3 is a little higher than box #2, you'd still want to fill it out left to right.  However, since box #1 is on a completely different X plane than the other boxes (regardless if it's further right than the rest) it still logically should come before the other boxes when filling out a form.  You wouldn't go across and then up.

Comment: @RichC Then you need in step 1 create groups of boxes which are overlaping. Sort the groups by Y axis, and then sort the boxes in the groups by X axis.

Comment: @TcKs yeah, I figured I'd have to do something like that but I was hoping there might already be some formula out there to mathematically figure this out with a numeric result I could order on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is how I was able to solve this:

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetFieldsOrderTest()
    {
        var fields = new List<TestFieldModel>()
                     {
                         new TestFieldModel()
                         {
                             ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 3,
                             PageNumber = 1,
                             X = 7,
                             Y = 6,
                             Width = 5,
                             Height = 2
                         },
                         new TestFieldModel()
                         {
                             ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 4,
                             PageNumber = 1,
                             X = 14,
                             Y = 4,
                             Width = 5,
                             Height = 3
                         },
                         new TestFieldModel()
                         {
                             ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 1,
                             PageNumber = 1,
                             X = 17,
                             Y = 9,
                             Width = 5,
                             Height = 3
                         },
                         new TestFieldModel()
                         {
                             ExpectedOrderNumberResult = 2,
                             PageNumber = 1,
                             X = 2,
                             Y = 5,
                             Width = 4,
                             Height = 2
                         }
                     };

        var pageCount = 1;
        for (var i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            var groups = new List<Group>();
            foreach (var field in fields.Where(f => f.PageNumber == i))
            {
                var needsNewGroup = true;
                foreach (var group in groups)
                {
                    var fieldTop = field.Y + field.Height;
                    var fieldBottom = field.Y;
                    if ((fieldTop <= group.Top && fieldTop >= group.Bottom) || (fieldBottom >= group.Bottom && fieldBottom <= group.Top))
                    {
                        if (fieldTop > group.Top)
                        {
                            group.Top = fieldTop;
                        }
                        if (fieldBottom < group.Bottom)
                        {
                            group.Bottom = fieldBottom;
                        }
                        group.GroupFields.Add(field);
                        needsNewGroup = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (needsNewGroup)
                {
                    var group = new Group
                                {
                                    Top = field.Y + field.Height,
                                    Bottom = field.Y,
                                    GroupFields = new List<TestFieldModel>
                                                  {
                                                      field
                                                  }
                                };
                    groups.Add(group);
                }
            }

            var groupFields = groups.OrderByDescending(g => g.Top).Select(g => g.GroupFields.OrderBy(gf => gf.X).ToList()).ToList();

            fields = groupFields.Aggregate((acc, list) => acc.Concat(list).ToList());

            fields.Should().HaveCount(4, "Count is not 4: " + fields.Count);
            fields[0].ExpectedOrderNumberResult.Should().Be(1, $"Expected 1.  Got {fields[0].ExpectedOrderNumberResult}.");
            fields[1].ExpectedOrderNumberResult.Should().Be(2, $"Expected 2.  Got {fields[1].ExpectedOrderNumberResult}.");
            fields[2].ExpectedOrderNumberResult.Should().Be(3, $"Expected 3.  Got {fields[2].ExpectedOrderNumberResult}.");
            fields[3].ExpectedOrderNumberResult.Should().Be(4, $"Expected 4.  Got {fields[3].ExpectedOrderNumberResult}.");

        }
    }

    public class Group
    {
        public List<TestFieldModel> GroupFields { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Bottom { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestFieldModel
    {

        public int ExpectedOrderNumberResult { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int Width { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is very similar to [yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67811642/64348). The main differences are

- not using a boolean to break out of two loops.
  In the "double break" scenario I prefer the maligned `goto`. It's subjective, but for me, is clearer because it avoids a check in the outer loop.
- replacing the `if` statements on recalculating group bounds with `Math.Min/Max`. This shorthand expresses your intent more clearly.
- calling `Group.Add()` for every field; there is no need to initialize the list of fields in a group differently if you have an empty list to being with

Psuedo C#:

```
foreach (var f in fields)
{
   foreach (var g in groups)
   {
      if (g.VerticallyOverlapsWith(f))
      {
          g.Add(f);
          goto NEXT_FIELD;
      }
   }
   
   // no overlap detected, so make a new group
   var newGroup = new Group();
   newGroup.Add(f);   
   groups.Add(newGroup)
   
   NEXT_FIELD :;
}

class Group
{
   void AddField(Field f)
   {
       _group.Add(f);
       _yTop = Max(f.Top, _yTop);
       _yBottom = Min(f.Bottom, _yBottom);
   }
   
   List<Field> _group = new List<Field>();
   int _yTop = int.MinValue();
   int _yBottom = int.MaxValue();
}
```

At this point you have your groups. You now have to sort groups descending then by fields ascending ([which you have done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67811642/64348)).

A couple of design points.

- this does not address fields that overlap with fields in multiple groups, causing unnecessarily large groups. If you get into that, your tabbing order could get a bit unexpected (from the user's point of view). If you expect these
  weird overlaps you'd be better off using a clustering algorithm or a "tolerance" function rather than a simple "overlap with first overlapping group" function (`VerticallyOverlapsWith` does the latter).
- you can avoid the sort steps at the end by making the adds insert into an ordered collection in each case.